# ASP.NET MVC without database INSERTS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used asp.net web forms before and currently thinking to switch to MVC, the issue is, my current project is against a 'real time database' - PI from OSISoft - where I don't need CRUD operations at all, its a view only application; is the MVC model still applicable here or what?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms are web application frameworks. They don't define any constraints on  data access. With a little refactoring you should be able to use same data access code (C# or VB) in an MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I just created a dashboard for a PI server. Used ASP.Net MVC and Web API to surface the information, it worked a treat.

Note MVC doesn't actually have anything to do with data persistence. It is simply a well-conceived UI design pattern.

Comment: Interesting Chris, by Web API do you mean the latest REST interface that OSISoft recently released? Also, were you accessing PI directly or thru an AF server?